# How to highlight cells in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cell, highlight, spyder

Hello,

I have been using vscode (Visual Studio Code) text editor for couple of days. I have come from Spyder IDE for python. I am developing a great likeness towards vscode. It encompasses all of my needs to python programming with also being lightweight.

However, *one thing that I am missing and wish it were here in vscode is **cell highlighting**. Though the editor has feature to segment the code into several cells by typing `# %%` before a block, it lacks the feature to highlight the cell where mouse pointer is hovered on.*

Maybe, there is an option there in *settings.json* but i don't know where it is in particular. Though it is not a great lack or causes major issues but i like to enable this feature in my vscode editor.

Below pictures illustrate my point. 
[image: cell highlighting absent in vscode]
[image]

Previous image is the visual studio code editor and the below one is for Spyder IDE.

Comment: Something's wrong with your images.

Comment: aren't they showing?

Comment: Please paste the code here instead of images.

Comment: Actually the problem is not code related. The images shows the absent of cell highlighting in vscode though i am not sure why they aren't showing to you since i have been able to see the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it is supported now.
Bellow there's a screenshot for the current version of VSCode using Microsoft's Python extension.

[image]

If this answers the question, please, inform as answer.

Comment: This is not highlighting of the cell, but only of the boundaries. If one of the cell borders are outside the field of view, you can't easily tell if it's the upper or lower cell that's highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to highlight cells with an extension. While this does not specifically target the currently selected cell, it makes cell editing much easier...

Highlight v1.9.0 by Fabio Spampinato
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight

I was able to add the following in `settings.json`:

```
"highlight.regexes":{
    "(#\\s*%%.*)": {
        "filterLanguageRegex": "python",
        "decorations": [
            {
                "backgroundColor": "#100000",
                "isWholeLine": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

There are options for multiline which may be helpful. Full set of css options is given here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DecorationRenderOptions